# one to one relationship in laravel (Error)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am new in Laravel, when I practice I get an error.
**at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\app\Http\routes.php', '144', array('id' => '1')) in routes.php line 144**

my **routes.php** file

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/post',function ($id){
  return  User::find($id)->post->title;
```

});

in my **User.php** file

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

I have two tables 1-posts 2-users
and I have also Post class 
[image]
I also google and search different sites but can't understand.
Please me,how to rid this Error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe because there is no user with that associated id

Comment: no, I have in the database

Comment: Can you test with User::find($id) and then User::find($id)->post

Comment: yeah i got `{"id":1,"name":"xyz","email":"ak.zu32@gamil.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}`

Comment: when i code `User::find($id)->post` .its displays me empty page without any error.

Comment: This entire relationship seems backwards? Can a user only have one post?

Comment: @Farkie user have two posts

Comment: @hasanmovahed Information Table needed for awnser this question? i didn't understand...?

Comment: Then how is it a one to one? Wouldn't it be a many to one (`belongsTo`) on posts, rather than a one to one from user?

Comment: @Farkie i used thats also in post.php `public  function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }`  but result is same(error)

Comment: i need table structural and information for answer this question .

Comment: @geckob when test `User::find($id)` it doesn't show me my one column that is` user_id` not `id`(auto increament)   `{"id":1,"name":"xyz","email":"ak.zu32@gamil.com","created_at‌​":null,"updated_at":‌​null}`

Comment: you are two tables but send pic of structural one table .

Answer (score 0):

your posts are one user . 
this renlship is "one-to-many" relationship . 
you must for this reason using this method in modal user :

```
 public function posts()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
 }
```

one to many is array from posts . 
for show resualt you must using foreach :

```
  $comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments;
  foreach ($comments as $comment) {
          $comment->title ;
  }
```

and reading this links : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: but same error `at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\app\Http\routes.php', '144', array('id' => '1')) in routes.php line 144`

Answer (score 0):

1:are you shure the relation is one to one;
2:if you shure add primary and foreign key and add this function in Post model.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','user_id');
}
```

Comment: now i got same Error!  `at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\app\Http\routes.php', '144', array('id' => '1')) in routes.php line 144`